2002 trailblazer trouble
We just replaced the starter in our trailblazer so it starts without problems and still have to replace the raidiator due to it leaking but now when driving it’s having trouble excelerating or getting into gear when I push on the gas makes a sputtering sound and is sluggish it catches and slowly very very slowly picks up. It had no problems like this before we replaced the starter what is causing this? What do we need to fix this

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the codes read?
